# Using std::max_element on a vector<double>

Tags: c++, vector, max, min

I'm trying to use `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` to return the minimum and maximum elements in a vector of doubles.  My compiler doesn't like how I'm currently trying to use them, and I don't understand the error message.  I could of course write my own procedure to find the minimum and maximum, but I'd like to understand how to use the functions.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    double cLower, cUpper;
    vector<double> C;

    // Code to insert values in C is not shown here

    cLower = min_element(C.begin(), C.end());
    cUpper = max_element(C.begin(), C.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compiler error:

```
../MIXD.cpp:84: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >' to 'double' in assignment
../MIXD.cpp:85: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >' to 'double' in assignment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that if you are using C++11 you can just use `std::minmax_element`.

Comment: @GManNickG: I didn't know of that function. I've added a note to my answer to incorporate this since the behaviour is different.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`min_element` and `max_element` return iterators, not values. So you need `*min_element...` and `*max_element...`.

Comment: An iterator is a pointer in that it points to things. But it may or may not be an ordinary pointer. For example, if an iterator refers to an object in a list, incrementing it makes it point to the next object in the list. Incrementing an ordinary pointer only does that for collections like a vector that are guaranteed to store their contents in sequence memory addresses.

Comment: in case the vector is empty `*max_element` raises error. Is there any solution to handle this issue? Right now I check if vector is empty or not and then use `*max_element`

Comment: I think that's the best solution. You need to handle the case specially anyway, because there's no sensible value that can be returned.

Comment: @Moj: you can check the iterator against `C.end()`.

Answer (score 57):

As others have said, [**`std::max_element()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and [**`std::min_element()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) return [*iterators*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#C.2B.2B), which need to be *dereferenced* to obtain the *value*.

The advantage of returning an iterator (rather than just the value) is that it allows you to determine the *position* of the (first) element in the container with the maximum (or minimum) value.

For example (using C++11 for brevity):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

    auto biggest = std::max_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    std::cout << "Max element is " << *biggest
        << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(v), biggest) << std::endl;

    auto smallest = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    std::cout << "min element is " << *smallest
        << " at position " << std::distance(std::begin(v), smallest) << std::endl;
}
```

This yields:

```
Max element is 5 at position 4
min element is 1 at position 0
```

---

### Note:

Using [**`std::minmax_element()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) as suggested in the comments above may be faster for large data sets, but may give slightly different results. The *values* for my example above would be the same, but the position of the "max" element would be `9` since...

> If several elements are equivalent to the largest element, the iterator to the last such element is returned.

Comment: @synaptik: This should work with other container types, too :)

Answer (score 26):

min/max_element return the *iterator* to the min/max element, not the value of the min/max element. You have to dereference the iterator in order to get the value out and assign it to a double. That is:

```
cLower = *min_element(C.begin(), C.end());
```