# Segmentation fault trying to dereference an iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to find the maximum value of a vector using std::max_element. When I run the program I get a segmentation fault that I believe is to do with std::end going over the end of the vector? I've tried changing it to std::end(tempdata)-1) but to no avail.

```
    auto max = std::max_element(std::begin(tempdata), std::end(tempdata));
    std::ofstream maxcurrent("maxcurrent.txt", std::ios::app);
    maxcurrent << v << std::setw(15) << *max << std::endl;
```

Having looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10159170) I don't see why mine isn't working.

Comment: Which line segfaults? The `std::max_element()` invocation (as the question's text suggests) or the `*max` dereference (as the question's title suggests)? And is `tempdata` nonempty?

Comment: are you searching for max element on an empty vector?

Comment: @Angew it's the *max line that segfaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't work when `max` is `std::end(tempdata)` which can occurs if your `tempdata` is empty.

> Iterator to the greatest element in the range [first, last). If several elements in the range are equivalent to the greatest element, returns the iterator to the first such element. Returns last if the range is empty.

[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Comment: I found that data wasn't getting written to tempdata properly, it's fixed now. Thank you.